# concatenating value to value in c# code -- Asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an anchor and I am assigning the the id to this anchor dynamically

```
<li>
  <a href="#" 
     name="offset" onclick="return so(this);" 
     data-val="@Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(ViewBag.lst[0].ca/2))" 
     id='javascript:"a+@Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(ViewBag.lst[0].ca / 2))"'>Last</a>
</li>
```

I supposed to get a3 or a4 or a5 because this `@Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(ViewBag.lst[0].ca / 2))` returns numeric value.

But I am getting "`a+3`" or "`a+4`". Apparently it is concatenating the plus sign too.

What I am trying to do above is simple string concatenation. This above code is from asp.net mvc view.

Comment: why do you need js there in the first place?

Comment: Did any of the answers work out for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` is not evaluated as operator rather treated as a *string*, you can use `string.Concat` to concatenate the string and your *expression*.

```
 <li><a href="#" name="offset" onclick="return so(this);" data-val="@Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(ViewBag.lst[0].ca/2))"
       id='@string.Concat("a",Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(ViewBag.lst[0].ca / 2)))'>Last</a></li>
```

Comment: now it's returning "a@Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(ViewBag.lst[0].ca / 2))"

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing this inside your cshtml (I suppose), you could avoid the ugliness of inline javascript and simply use:

```
 @("a"+ Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(ViewBag.lst[0].ca / 2))
```